# View Gmail messages linked by In-Reply-To header?

Tags: gmail

Gmail's conversation view is broken, thus I kept it turned off:

[image]

But this would unlink all messages linked by In-Reply-To header.

How do I view Gmail messages linked by In-Reply-To header?

Comment: You probably need to look for a third-party solution.

Comment: AFAIK Gmail web app do nothing in relation to "In-Reply-To" header. May soon a Gmail add-on will solve this.